# How to get position of element pushed into array in $group stage

Tags: javascript, mongodb

How to get position of element pushed into array in $group stage?

In my collection 'xxx' I have documents:

```
[
  {
    login: login1,
    group: 1,
    a: 3,
    b: 1
  },
  {
    login: login2,
    group: 2,
    a: 2,
    b: 3
  },
  {
    login: login3,
    group: 1,
    a: 5,
    b: 3
  },
]
```

My query is something like this:

```
db.collection('xxx').aggregate( 
  [ 
    { $project: { login: 1, group: 1, sumAB: { $sum: [ '$a', '$b'] } } },
    { $sort: { group: 1, sumAB: -1 } },
    { $group: { _id: '$group', users: { $push: { login: '$login', positionInArray: here i want the index of pushed element in array 'users' } } } } },
    { $unwind: '$users' },
    { $match: { 'users.login': { $in: ['login1', 'login2'] } } } 
  ], function(err, result) { .. }
```

I want to have access to result[0].users.positionInArray and result[1].users.positionInArray to compare which one is bigger.

EDIT:
I found a solution. It's 'includeArrayIndex' option in $unwind stage.

```
db.collection('gracze').aggregate(  [                                                                                                       
  { $project: { login: 1, group: 1, sumAB: { $sum: [ '$a', '$b'] } } },
  { $sort: { group: 1, sumaAB: -1 } },
  { $group: { _id: '$group', users: { $push: { login: '$login' } } } },
  { $unwind: { path: '$users', includeArrayIndex: 'positionInArray' } }, 
  { $match: { 'users.login': { $in: ['login1', 'login2'] } } } 
], function(err, result) { .. }
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what you really want to achieve here. But I have a feeling you're going overly complex here. What exactly is your goal of this query? Perhaps, this helps: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/

Comment: I solved my problem by using 'includeArrayIndex' option in $unwind stage, thanks anyway